# alias or select AS for legacy data in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, alias

I've got a rails app that is connecting to a legacy database.

when I query the db, it returns stuff like 'userID', instead of 'id' and 'userName' instead of 'name'.

I thought it would be simple enough to just write in my controllers

```
:select=>'userID AS id, userName AS name'
```

but when I do that, the fields I'm attempting to rename don't get returned. Other fields that I'm not aliasing are getting returned.

Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe aliasing the field names in the models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you define the changes in your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "userID"
  #Use alias_attribute to define your columns to ActiveRecord standards.
  alias_attribute "name", "userName"
end
```

Or you can use the recomended route and create a view for your database on the server.

For more information see: http://www.slideshare.net/napcs/rails-and-legacy-databases-railsconf-2009